# Set value to payload using expression transformer

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I am wanting to invoke a function on payload which is a Java pojo to set a value.

```
<set-variable variableName="name" value="xyz" doc:name="Variable"/>
<foreach doc:name="For Each">
<expression-transformer expression="#[payload.setEventId(flowVars['name'])]" doc:name="Expression"/>
<logger message="#[payload.getEventId()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</foreach>
```

But this is giving me error.
Root Exception stack trace: 
org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException: Expression Evaluator "null" with expression "payload.setEventId(flowVars['name'])" returned null but a value was required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `expression-transformer` replaces the current payload with the value returned by the expression. I'm guessing `setEventId` is void thus the expression returns `null`, hence the exception.

Use an `expression-component` instead:

```
<expression-component>payload.setEventId(flowVars['name'])</expression-component>
```

Comment: Along similar lines in the expression component I am doing below but getting a boolean(true) payload = flowVars.userList.add(payload) Here userList is an ArrayList

Comment: Yep, indeed `ArrayList.add` returns a bool: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29